# Did Peter's mother know that Ego was not human?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

Is there any evidence which shows that Peter's mother knew Ego was an alien?

Comment: In GOTG1, she told him at her death bed that he was made out of pure light, so she knew somehow that he wasn't from this world.

Comment: Did you actually watch either of these films?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

- On her deathbed, Meredith tells Peter, "You're so like your daddy. You even look like him. **And he was an angel. Composed out of pure light**."
- Meredith's nickname for Peter is "My little **Star-Lord**," which Peter later takes as his code name.
- When Ego **shows her his space seedling thing** behind the Dairy Queen, Ego says that soon it will be all across **the universe**. Meredith says "I can't believe I fell in love **with a space man**."

And, most convincingly,

- When Peter meets Ego he says "My mother told everyone my father was **from the stars**."